# Is Git auto stashing?

Tags: git

I am currently on a branch and made some changes, did not commit or stash. I switched to another branch, git did not give me the usual

`error: Your local changes to the following files will be overwritten by checkout: Please commit your changes or stash before you can switch branches.`

Instead it just switched to the other branch and carried the changes with it. How do I fix this? I want to have the error back and prevents me from switching until i commit it.

Comment: Was it a new branch you switched to?

Comment: @trudbert it was an existing branch i switched to, but it gives me the error on another project. Just this current project im on, it doesnt give the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git prevents you from altering your working directory in a way that overwrites local changes (e.g. in case of a checkout).

Since your checkout went smooth, it simply means that the local changes were not overwritten by it, so there's no need to worry. You're still in a consistent state.

Were you switching to a new branch perhaps? Or maybe the local changes were newly added files? That would explain why the checkout generated no conflicts.